# Mule - Configure dynamically an SQS Connector

Tags: mule, mule-studio

i'm trying to pass in a dynamic way the connection details to an SQS Connector. Is this possible to accomplish?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the connector supports connection management, so the connection details can either be configured globally or dynamically per operation during a flow:

```
<sqs:config name="sqs" region="USEAST1" />

    <flow name="sqs" processingStrategy="synchronous">

        <sqs:send-message config-ref="sqs" accessKey="#[flowVars.accessKey]"
            secretKey="#[flowVars.secretKey]" queueName="#[flowVars.queueName]"
            queueUrl="#[flowVars.queueUrl]" />
    </flow>
```

The only global parameter that needs to be set is the region.